# Why does the package-info.java file affect annotation-processing?

Tags: javac, annotation-processing, package-info

Adding a [package-info.java](https://gitlab.com/pck-info-issue/java-only/blob/master/src/com/example/package-info.java) file to the project, causes annotation-processors to create different output.

I don't understand why this happens. I think adding the [package-info.java](https://gitlab.com/pck-info-issue/java-only/blob/master/src/com/example/package-info.java) file should not affect my build at all, because it does not contain any fancy stuff (like Annotations, etc.). It only contains the simplest package declaration:

```
package com.example;
```

I've managed to create a minimal project to reproduce the issue with `javac` only. The project has too much code to post here on StackOverflow, so I've published the project on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/pck-info-issue/java-only): including the full source-code and a very detailed README file.

Any ideas why this happens or what could be the cause? Is it maybe a java-bug?

Notes

- the project uses a jar file `color-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` as library, which:

  - uses the same annotation processor
  - uses the same package (in the real project, we must use the same package name in different modules to use the java package-scope)
- the problem can also be reproduced in an Android project with another annotation processor: see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393034/immutables-library-generates-the-same-immutable-class-twice)

Comment: see [issue JDK-8185952](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8185952)

Comment: see [issue JDK-8183187](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8183187)